# Javascript boolean expression not working properly

Tags: javascript, express

Please I need help on this code.
I have created a page with a single input field with the name="searchWork" where I input the search keyword and send.

On the "if" statement where the boolean resides, only the first comparison works (the comparison against the .state element, but the .lgaName and the .nameOfCommunity are not working. That is whenever I search the states in my object array, the object get populated with relevant data, but when I searched lga or community name, it displays an empty object, meaning the object is not populated with any data.
I don't know where I went wrong on the comparison or something.

Thank you.

```
function getSearch(req, res, next) {
    let theProjects = shared.projects;
    let dataObject = {};
    const search = req.body.searchWork;
    for (let i = 0; i < theProjects.length; i++) {
        if ((search === theProjects[i].state) || (search === theProjects[i].lga[i].lgaName) || (search === theProjects[i].lga[i].communities[i].nameOfCommunity)) {
            dataObject.state = theProjects[i].state;
            dataObject.lga = theProjects[i].lga[i].lgaName;
            dataObject.community = theProjects[i].lga[i].communities[i].nameOfCommunity;
            dataObject.project = theProjects[i].lga[i].communities[i].projects.building;
        }
    }
    console.log(dataObject);

    next();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use boolean AND (`&&`) instead of OR (`||`) ?

Comment: You seem to have a 2d array for "lga", it seems improbable that "i" would be a valid index for both. Perhaps you need a nested search?

Comment: @tromgy No I meant to use OR (II) not AND (&&) as any of the search should work.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think that's where the problem lies as the outer array is not the same length as the inner arrays. I will use 2d array and see if it works.

Comment: @MisbahuAbubakar You *are* using a "2d" array (a nested array). If the intent is to search within that nested array then it would also need to be iterated.